# Why is _mainCRTStartup so slow with debugging on, but fast with debugging off?

Tags: c++, winapi, glut

I'm using 32-bit GLUT on 64-bit Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010. The project just contains my C++ implementation and header files. No Win32-specific code.

I do a lot of pixel drawing operations. It's instantaneous with the release configuration, but very slow (at least 5 seconds until it draws) with the debug configuration. I noticed it slowed down more when I drew more. So I figured, profile it.

The Visual C++ profiler says 100% (I'm guessing that's rounded up) of the time is spent in `_mainCRTStartup`. I understand this is the C run time, but what's causing it to run so slowly in the debug configuration? The equivalent C code is equally instantaneous when in both debug and release configurations. Is there anything special with C++ that makes `_mainCRTStartup` take much longer?

**EDIT:** Apparently I overlooked one thing: under _mainCRTStartup frame, there is a reference to `Unknown frame(s)`. I assume this is the `main()` and its children functions. I cannot get it to actually profile the functions I wrote, either in debug or release. Where do I go after this?

Comment: `_mainCRTStartup` calls `main` -- I'm guessing that 100% is for main() from start to end which is obviously your entire running time ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that tidbit. Makes sense.

But doesn't explain the 5 second lag before it draws. :(

Comment: You need to be less coarse if you want to find out what's taking time (although caring about the performance of debug is a bit useless). Saying 100% of the time is taken by the start-up code (which calls `main()`) is trivial and uninformative.

Comment: I just figured that out. I edited the question to add the fact that I have unknown frames after _mainCRTStartup. I need to figure out how to get Visual C++ to actually profile my functions. Thanks, GMan!

Answer (score 1):

The debugger is probably having trouble finding the .pdb files for the DLLs that you use.  First thing to do is to check your symbol server settings.  Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols.  Uncheck the Symbol file locations and try again.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like nothing was checked.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the main() method.  How long does it take to get there after you press F5?

Comment: It's pretty instantaneous. I just did the classical millisecond comparison. Looks like the problem is in the drawing function. In release configuration, it takes 93 ms, in debug configuration, it takes 3884 ms. Visual C++ still doesn't see more frames after `_mainCRTStartup`. While 93 ms is pretty good performance, I'd still like to know which was the most expensive calls and all. Thanks!

Comment: Try not to spend time optimizing the debug build, there's no point.  The difference is far too large to easily explain, see what effect the settings in the Code Generation page have on this.

Answer (score 0):

What the "exclusive % samples" in `_mainCRTStartup`?  Inclusive samples are worthless for this routine.

Answer (score 0):

`_mainCRTStartup` is the primary function that calls `main`. So yes, for every program, 100% of the time is spent inside that function- because it calls all other functions.

You're profiling Debug mode? Just why?

Comment: Because the startup is super slow compared to a release run. And it's also slower than the C equivalent in both debug and release. I'm assuming _mainCRTStartup is also called for the C equivalent. So why is C so much faster than C++ in debug mode?

Also, I probably should have mentioned it in the question. But apparently _mainCRTStartup has unknown frame(s). I'm assuming the frames are my main() and the functions that are eventually called. But they don't appear in the profiler. I'll edit the question.

EDIT: Grr, I forgot to shift+enter.